# when called from xcode, my bash script does not get environment variables in .bash_profile

Tags: xcode, bash, shell

In Xcode 5 I have a build phase that executes a bash script. 
My problem is that when that script is called from Xcode, it does not have access to the environment variables that I have set in my .bash_profile.

I have tried to created an environement.plist file from xcode and duplicate my environment variables there, but still the bash script remains unaware of my variables.
One thing I can do is call source ~/.bash_profile from myscript. But in my bash_profile I have lines like

```
export PATH=/some/new/path:$PATH
```

so calling source ~/.bash_profile everytime xcode compile my project, will prepend /some/new/path to my path over and over again.

How do I make my script aware of environment variables when called from xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with sourcing `~/.bash_profile`. When Xcode runs your script, it calls the script, the script prepends `/some/new/path` to the `PATH`, compiles your project and exits. When Xcode runs your script again, the new script doesn't have the updated `PATH`, because it's a different process from the earlier run. So `/some/new/path` is not prepended "over and over again", it only happens once in the lifetime of the script. Each compilation triggers a completely new script, their environment is not shared, `PATH` does not grow forever.

Comment: my script needs the PATH variable in order to run. So with your solution i'd still have to put the PATH variable line described above in my separate script and thus reload it and append/prepend paths everytime

Comment: @Baba I overlooked the last bit in your question. I updated my answer now.